# Subnavigation menu with 2 columns

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement a submenu with two distinct columns when the user hover in "Our Services". What I  have done is:

1. I implemented 2 different `ul .submenu-content` inside the `li .submenu`, Our Services.
2. For `.submenu` i decided to display it as a `grid` because I need to distinc columns with `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;`
3. For `.submenu-content` I set the position to `absolute`

Now both submenus `ul` are at the exact same position and I can't figure out what is wrong. [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5kHX.jpg)

What I want is just two columns and 1 column = 1 ul

**HTML **

```html
    <ul class="nav-links">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about/about.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li class="submenu" ><a href="#" >Our Services</a>
            <ul class="submenu-content">
                <li>AA </li>
                <li>BB</li>
                <li>CC </li>
                <li>DDD</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="submenu-content">
                <li>Recruitment expefgggfrtise </li>
                <li>Executive dffd</li>
                <li>Mass Recruitmdfdfent </li>
                <li>Database df</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="search/search.php">Job Search</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://blog.asia-hr.com">Newsletter</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact/contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
```

**CSS for submenues**

```css
    .submenu {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    }

    .submenu-content{
        position: absolute;
    }
```

**CSS for navbar**

```css
    #navbar{
        z-index: 10000;
        width: 100%;
        widows: 100%;
        padding:20px;
        position: fixed;
        transition: .5s;
        display: flex;
        justify-content:space-between;
    }

    #navbar .logo{
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }


    #navbar .nav-links{
        margin-left: auto;
        display:flex;
        align-items:center;
        list-style:none;
    }

    #navbar .nav-links li a{
        color:#34495e;
        letter-spacing:2px;
        padding: 0.75rem;
        margin: 0 0.2rem;
    }

    #navbar .nav-links li a:hover{
        color: rgb(196, 115, 11);
    }
```

Comment: Have you had a look at this codepen for Bootstrap 2 column dropdown layout? https://codepen.io/dustlilac/pen/Qwpxbp

Comment: Just had a look! Seems interesting since they provide HTML & CSS!

Comment: It might give you something to work off !